# Is enforcing an abstract method implementation unpythonic?

Tags: python, oop

When designing classes abstract methods can be very helpful. From what I know, Python does not have a mechanism for enforcing an inherited class to implement the abstract method. In my code (see example below) I enter a failed assertion in the base class to cause a runtime error if not implemented. Is this unpythonic?

```
class Dog(Animal):
  def speak(self):
   return "bark"

class Animal():
  def speak(self):
   assert(False) #abstract
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Python actually *does* have abstract classes with abstact methods:

```
>>> import abc
>>> 
>>> class IFoo(object):
...     __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
...     
...     @abc.abstractmethod
...     def foo(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> foo = IFoo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Cant instantiate abstract class IFoo with abstract methods foo
>>> class FooDerived(IFoo):
...     pass
... 
>>> foo = FooDerived()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Cant instantiate abstract class FooDerived with abstract methods foo
>>> class FooImplements(FooDerived):
...     def foo(self):
...         print "foo'ed"
... 
>>> foo = FooImplements()
>>> foo.foo()
foo'ed
>>>
```

On the other hand, the fundamental question of *"is this pythonic"* is a bit harder to say.  If your intent is to provide the abstract base class so that you can later check to make sure that values inherit from it, then no, that's not particularly pythonic, even though it's possible to make arbitrary types abstract subclasses of your baseclass.  On the other hand, it's perfectly fine to provide an abstract baseclass that implements some functionality based upon the implementation provided in concrete subclasses.  For example, `collections.Sequence` and `collections.Mapping` do just this for list like and dict like classes; subclasses can provide `__getitem__` and can get `__contains__` and others for free.

For certain, you should never use `assert()` except to document the expectations of code;  If it's actually possible for the assert to fail, you shouldn't be using an assert.  Optimized python (`python -O script.py`) does not check assertions.

Edit: more exposition:

If you are checking the type of a value:

```
def foo(bar):
    if not isinstance(bar, AbstractBaz):
        raise ValueError, ("bar must be an instance of AbstractBaz, "
                           "got %s" % type(bar))
```

If for some reason you can't use `@abstractmethod`, but still want that effect, you should raise `NotImplementedError`.  You might want to do this because you actually do want instances of that class, some of which might not need to implement optional functionality.  You still should account for the possibility that the function was called through `super()`.  To a first approximation, that might look like this.

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self, baz):
        if self.bar.im_func == Foo.bar.im_func:
            raise NotImplementedError, "Subclasses must implement bar"
```

Comment: I tried your example with Python 3.8 and it gives no exception.

Comment: @UMR In Python 3, instead of `__metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta`, use `class IFoo(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):`

Answer (score 5):

ABCs are an artifact of C++ and are contrary to duck-typing. If class Animal did not define `speak` it would do what you intend with no effort at all.

```
>>> class Animal(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> class Dog(Animal):
...     def speak(self):
...             print "bark"
... 
>>> animal = Animal()
>>> dog = Dog()
>>> animal.speak()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Animal' object has no attribute 'speak'
>>> dog.speak()
bark
```

C++ and related languages force you to create ABCs because the ABC is actually an interface description. Python eschews compiler-enforced interface declarations as they attempt to document – in code – a contract that is better enforced through extra-linguistic means.

Comment: "Python eschews compiler-enforced interface declarations as they attempt to document – in code – a contract that is better enforced through extra-linguistic means." WTF? Please clarify this statement, it might make it more helpful to others.

Comment: Further, ABCs and/or abstract methods are perfectly valid in the duck typing world if you require that users of your library implement a method of say a mix in class. Who cares if it's "unpythonic" or counter to the indoctrinated beliefs of a particular community if it's proper software engineering. Have a look at TokenMacGuy's answer below and ignore this guy.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you don’t include the method `speak` in your base class and somehow happen to use it, the code fails anyway. The question is, how probable is it and how to tell the user (a `NotImplementedError` might fit better here than an assertion).

Answer (score 0):

With python in general it can be not always possible to directly enforce restrictions on the code, at least from the object oriented point of view (thinking about abstract classes, private methods, ...).
To enforce a subclass to implement a method you may want to do something like:

```
class Animal():
  def speak(self):
   raise NotImplementedError #abstract

class Dog(Animal):
  def speak(self):
   return "bark"

class MuteAnimal(Animal):
  pass
```

This doesn't imply that the method will be implemented by the subclass, but it will simply raise an error when the speak method is not implemented.