# Duck typing and (java) interface concept

Tags: python, interface

I just read the Wikipedia article about [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), and I feel like I miss an important point about the interface concept I used to in Java:

```
"When I see a bird that walks like a duck and swims like a duck and quacks like a duck, I call that bird a duck."


class Duck:
    def quack(self):
        print("Quaaaaaack!")
    def feathers(self):
        print("The duck has white and gray feathers.")
    def swim(self):
        print("Swim seamlessly in the water")

class Person:
    def quack(self):
        print("The person imitates a duck.")
    def feathers(self):
        print("The person takes a feather from the ground and shows it.")
    def name(self):
        print("John Smith")

def in_the_forest(duck):
    duck.quack()
    duck.feathers()

def game():
    donald = Duck()
    john = Person()
    in_the_forest(donald)
    in_the_forest(john)

game()
```

what if, in `in_the_forest`, I write:

- does it `quack` like a duck ? yes
- does it have a duck `feathers` ? yes
- great, it's a duck we've got !

and later, because I know it's a duck, I want it to `swim`? `john` will sink!

I don't want my application to crash (randomly) in the middle of its process just because John faked to be a duck, but I guess it wouldn't be a wise idea to check every single attributes of the object when I receive it ... ?

Comment: In short, you don't worry. You write good tests that cover as many code paths and corner cases as humanly possible, but 100% security is never possible. And note that you can't have 100% security with Java or most other static type systems either ;)

Comment: +1: a really well presented question about an important subject, with counts with great answers. Sorry I can just give it only 1 upvote.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Duck typing isn't really about checking whether the things you need are there and then using them. Duck typing is about just using what you need.

The `in_the_forest` function was written by a developer who was thinking about ducks. It was designed to operate on a `Duck`. A `Duck` can `quack` and `feathers`, so the coder used those features to get the job at hand done. In this case, the fact that a `Duck` can also `swim` wasn't used, and wasn't needed.

In a static language like Java, `in_the_forest` would have been declared to take a `Duck`. When the coder later discovered that they had a `Person` (which could also `quack` and `feathers`) and wanted to reuse the function, they're out of luck. Is a `Person` a subclass of `Duck`? No, that doesn't seem at all appropriate. Is there a `QuacksAndFeathers` interface? Maybe, if we're lucky. Otherwise we'll have to make one, go modify `Duck` to implement it, and modify `in_the_forest` to take a `QuacksAndFeathers` instead of a `Duck`. This may be impossible if `Duck` is in an external library.

In Python, you just pass your Person to `in_the_forest` and it works. Because it turns out `in_the_forest` doesn't need a `Duck`, it just needs a "duck-like" object, and in this case Person is sufficiently duck-like.

`game` though, needs a different definition of "duck-like", which is slightly stronger. Here, John Smith is out of luck.

Now, it's true that Java would have caught this error at compile time and Python won't. That can be viewed as a disadvantage. The pro-dynamic-typing counter argument is to say that any substantial body of code you write will always contain bugs that **no** compiler can catch (and to be honest, Java isn't even a particularly good example of a compiler with strong static checks to catch lots of bugs). So you need to test your code to find those bugs. And if you're testing for those bugs, you will trivially find bugs where you passed a `Person` to a function that needs a `Duck`. Given that, the dynamic-typist says, a language that tempts you into **not** testing because it finds *some* of your trivial bugs is actually a *bad* thing. And on top of that, it prevents you from doing some really useful things, like reusing the `in_the_forest` function on a `Person`.

Personally I'm torn in two directions. I really like Python with its flexible dynamic typing. And I really like Haskell and [Mercury](http://www.csse.unimelb.edu.au/research/mercury) for their powerful static type systems. I'm not much of a fan of Java or C++; in my opinion they have all of the bad bits of static typing with few of the good bits.

Comment: Some people think of static typing as a kind of built-in unit testing system, but I don't really miss it. It's just like in real life: if a person wakes up in random collection of objects and looks over to see a duck sitting next to them, something went seriously wrong a good while back.

Comment: Oh wait, I miss it when I want Eclipse's autocomplete to show me useful things. That's it.

Comment: +1 with gratuitous soapbox: you want type safety in a language populated by ints? You need Pascal's ranged integer types if you don't want to see a duck sitting beside you (and no one wants ranged integers (and enums up to 2^16 would be silly))

Comment: `a language that tempts you into not testing ... is a bad thing` I think you're right with this point and I'll need to manage to turn my mind into it!

Comment: Python doesn't stop you from omitting unit tests either. Does it suddenly stop to work if you don't include unit tests? Nope. Unit testing or not doesn't depend on the language (and even one of the most popular unit testing framework, jUnit, is written for Java). `The pro-dynamic-typing counter argument is to say that any substantial body of code you write will always contain bugs that no compiler can catch`: Just because we're gonna die one day, doesn't mean that we shouldn't try to live a healthy life. IMO, dynamic languages are pain in the ass when we try to start refactoring.

Answer (score 5):

Can't speak for other languages, but in python it has been recently (v2.6) introduced the [Abstract Base Classes (ABC) module](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html).

If you read the rationale behind its introduction ([PEP 3119](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/#rationale)) you will quickly realise that part of the reason was to "save john from sure death" or in other words, to facilitate the check on the fact when you program to an interface, all interface methods will be there. From the linked PEP:

> ABCs are simply Python classes that
>   are added into an object's inheritance
>   tree to signal certain features of
>   that object to an external inspector.
>   Tests are done using isinstance(), and
>   the presence of a particular ABC means
>   that the test has passed. In addition,
>   the ABCs define a minimal set of
>   methods that establish the
>   characteristic behavior of the type.
>   Code that discriminates objects based
>   on their ABC type can trust that those
>   methods will always be present.

In general, **you can apply the same pattern for your own code**. For example: you can create a `BasePlugin` class with all the methods needed for a plugin to work, and you can then create several different plugins by subclassing it. Depending on whether each plugin *must* or *can* have those methods defined, you can define `BasePlugin` methods to silently pass (plugins *can* define those methods) or to raise an exception (plugins *must* define those methods / override the `BasePlugin`'s one).

**EDIT:** In the thread of comments below, I have been suggested to include in the answer this bit of discussion:

> This kind of features - at least in python - are not implemented for the sake of the human programmer (python never silence an error, so there's already plenty of feedback there), but rather for the sake of python own introspection capability (thus making easier to write dynamic loading, metaprogramming code, etc...). In other words: I know John can't fly... but I want the python interpreter to know it too! :)

Comment: Just because you can use Java-isms that simulate static typing doesn't mean that you ought. I've yet to see a non-toy class implementation whereby the user of a heterogeneous list doesn't already know whether John can fly.

Furthermore, suppose your `isinstance` check fails, you have to cope with it anyway. How does this differ from an `except` block? ("Inheritance may be one of the most seductively overused features of OOP" -me)

Comment: @msw - I don't know java so the parallel doesn't help me much understand your observation (I'm all ears if you have an opportunity to rephrase, though!). Keep in mind that most of this kind of features - at least in python - are not implemented for the sake of the human programmer (python never silence an error, so there's already plenty of feedback there), but rather for the sake of python own introspection capability (thus making easier to write dynamic loading, metaprogramming code, etc...). In other words: I know John can't fly... but I want the python interpreter to know it too! :)

Comment: the Python interpreter does know it. I would have recapitulated my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576837/is-enforcing-an-abstract-method-implementation-unpythonic/6576986#6576986 but felt that I was being a mite dogmatic today. My "Java-ism" could apply to many currently popular OOP languages (e.g. C++). I find http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html useful for breaking old mindsets. Your point regarding metaprogramming etc. should be more obvious than 'tis to the non-metaprogrammer (but so should C++ dynamic_casts (why is the feature there if not to use ;) )

Comment: Ben's answer better states my comments.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, dynamic class loading is what I actually had on the back on my mind, so it will help me to solve my problem

Answer (score 5):

> I don't want my application to crash (randomly) in the middle of its process just because John faked to be a duck, but I guess it wouldn't be a wise idea to check every single attributes of the object when I receive it ... ?

That's an issue of *dynamic typing* in general. In a statically typed language like Java, the compiler checks at compile time whether `Person` implements `IDuck` or not. In a dynamically typed language like Python, you get a run-time error if `Person` misses some particular duck feature (such as `swim`). To quote another Wikipedia article (["Type system", Section "Dynamic Typing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_typing)):

> Dynamic typing may result in runtime type errors—that is, at runtime, a value may have an unexpected type, and an operation nonsensical for that type is applied. Such errors may occur long after the place where the programming mistake was made—that is, the place where the wrong type of data passed into a place it should not have. This may make the bug difficult to locate.

Dynamic typing has its drawbacks (you have mentioned one) and its advantages. A brief comparison can be found in another section of the Type system article in Wikipedia: [Static and dynamic type checking in practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_and_dynamic_type_checking_in_practice).

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic typing strength, Duck Typing has another card up its sleeve, to enable implementing multiple interfaces, i.e. multiple independent behaviour traits.

Formal Interfaces, using ABCs are great and can gives you early failure. However you can still only implement one 'interface' at a time (you can inherit from one parent class).

Besides, using class inheritance you soon end up in a mess due to its innate chain and lead to tight coupling and blind alleys. An error due to a change up the chain will impact all the related code which may not have been tested nor have full test coverage.

Whereas classes that use composition instead promote independency.
A dev can plan the UML with necessary interfaces to add multiple behaviour traits (e.g. ILogger, IEventGenerator, ICalcArea...) and in the code mask the multiple interfaces using duck typing. Of course the drawback is the dev needs to plan carefully to prevent name collisions and as the OP points out, missing a property or method will end as a runtime error rather than compiler warning.

Back to the old strength / weakness trade in.