# Why is it possible to use Python vanilla max() to numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

ndarray is a datatype defined specifically in numpy, so I wonder why I can use the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
max(a) --> 4
```

I assume that python converts this back to a list, but I don't understand how this is done automatically and how python "knows" HOW to convert it to a list?

In addition, this one doesn't work:

```
b = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
max(b)
```

so in this case, python obviously doesn't know HOW to convert this to a list. Why does numpy not automatically flatten the multidimensional array to a vector like this:

```
max(b.flatten(1))
```

thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting. I had already read the documentation and saw the `max(iterable[, key=func])` but couldn't quite understand the meaning of the iterable myself. I thought SO would be for questions like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The max function has the following arguments:

```
max(iterable[, key=func]) -> value
max(a, b, c, ...[, key=func]) -> value
```

In the numpy array case the numpy array is treated as an iterable. 
In the case of your b what will happen is that b gets iterated over.
This results in:

```
>>> list(iter(b))
[array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])]
```

Now if you compare the two items with the default comparison function you'll get the same error:

```
>>> c = list(iter(b))
>>> cmp(c[0], c[1])
```

Numpy does not flatten the array as the iterator will loop, [by default](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html#default-iteration), over rows and not over elements. If you want more control over the iteration, you can use on of the array iterators such as:

the [`numpy.nditer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html)  function.

```
>>> max(np.nditer(b))
array(6)
```

or the [`.flat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html#numpy.ndarray.flat) attribute:

```
>>> max(b.flat)
6
```

Comment: Ah very nice, okay I see. So the most-outer element in the list/ndarray is being iterated instead of the most-inner elements (i.e. in case of `b` that would be the single values)

Comment: Thanks for your edit, great to see. It's nice to see so many possibilities but at the same time, it's very confusing and sometimes tough to get a real insight into it.

Comment: Indeed a lot of options. As an extra option, you can replace `max(b)` by `b.max()`.

Comment: Yeah that was also something I was wondering about: Why is numpy "confusing" its users by giving so many redundant implementations: `numpy.max(b)` vs `numpy.amax(b)` (okay maybe because `amax` has more options itself) but then it's even implemented as a method to ndarray: `b.max()`. Weird stuff. Why not only offering one single method `np.max(b)` so that it's clear? In my opinion: Even if it's easily possible to offer the ndarray-method (probably calling back to `np.max()` itself again...), it's not necessary at all to offer it.

Comment: @SiggyF: I'd be interested in the same question as tim asked in the last comment. Why is `max` implemented in so many ways?

Comment: I assume at least due to the following. Numpy supports both a scripting style of programming `max(a)` and an objected oriented programming style `a.max()`. The first one fits in with what scientists and engineers would expect when they move over from matlab (see the [pylab](http://wiki.scipy.org/PyLab) discussion). As people "grow" towards more advanced programmers they tend to favour the object oriented approach and use namespaces instead of the `from pylab import *` approach. In the specific case of max, python already has the procedural style max, and not `list.max`.

Answer (score 5):

The Python function [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) does not expect just lists as an argument but instead accepts an `iterable` object as shown in the docs here:

```
max(iterable[, key])
```

It is not converting the numpy arrays to lists at all but is instead using the fact that numpy arrays are iterable (as are tuples, strings, etc).

Comment: Ah I see thanks, so the `iterable` is like an `interface` which is being implemented and thus `max` works for that type of datatypes all the same?

Comment: Yeah I would suggest looking up [Duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Also this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579671/duck-typing-and-java-interface-concept) may help given your background with interfaces.