# In Python, how can I enforce a method's input and output invariants in child classes?

Tags: python, typeerror, typechecking, method-signature, invariants

Is there a convenient way to enforce a method's input and output invariants, when the method is overridden in a subclass?

By enforcing invariants, I mean checking things like:

- The number of input arguments
- The types of some/all of the inputs
- The number of output arguments
- The types of some/all of the outputs

(Related questions have asked about [enforcing the # of input arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255808/how-to-enforce-method-signature-for-child-classes), but not the types. Others have asserted that [explicit type checking is unpythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858903/abstract-classes-in-python-enforcing-type), but, well, in this instance I don't care.)

For example, I have a base class B, with a method to be subclassed that takes an int and returns a float.

```python
class B(object):
    def returns_float(self, int_arg):
        raise NotImplementedException("implement me")
```

To enforce this int->float signature, I currently split the method into `returns_float()`, and its implementation, `_returns_float()`. The subclass overrides the latter.

```python
class B(object):
    def returns_float(self, int_arg):
        if not numpy.issubdtype(int_arg, 'int'):
            raise TypeError("Arg isn't an int.")

        result = self._returns_float(int_arg)

        if not numpy.issubdtype(result, 'float64'):
            raise TypeError("Return type isn't a float64")

        return result

    def _returns_float(self, int_arg):
        raise NotImplementedException("implement me")
```

This is flexible and explicit, but I'm wondering if there's some slicker way to do this?

Comment: What if a subclass wants to accept floats as well as ints?  That isn't a violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LiskovSubstitutionPrinciple), so you should probably allow the subclass to do it.

Comment: @Kevin Nice principle, but lets say I only want integral values here.

Comment: Hm... the problem I see with this is that someone can use [duck typing](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DuckTyping) and (possibly) [`ABCMeta.register()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register) to circumvent most any restrictions you can create, so I'm not sure if there's much point in trying.

Comment: @Kevin I'm not trying to prevent all errors, just the usual oversights. There's a point in trying.